# How to extract input part of a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, display

For example, how to make Mathematica display only the lines beginning with `In[some number]`?

```
In[8]:= m1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {8, 4, 2}, {64, 16, 4}}
```

> ```
> Out[8]= {{1, 1, 1}, {8, 4, 2}, {64, 16, 4}}
> ```

```
In[9]:= m1.{b1, b2, b3} == {1, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> Out[9]= {b1 + b2 + b3, 8 b1 + 4 b2 + 2 b3, 64 b1 + 16 b2 + 4 b3} == {1, 1, 1}
> ```

Comment: I've deleted part of your code as not relevant for the question. Feel free to revert this if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see three ways:

1. Copy and paste everything into a new notebook (to ensure we don't destroy the output for good).  Then select Cell -> Delete All Output from the menu.
2. <kbd>alt</kbd>-click (<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on a Mac) on an input cell's bracket.  All input cells will get selected.  Now copy them and paste them into a new notebook.
3. <kbd>alt</kbd>-click (<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on a Mac) on an input cell's bracket.  All input cells will get selected.  Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> on a Mac).  All outputs will be hidden, but they won't be deleted.

   (If you need to hide the input and keep the output, you can do the same but start with alt-clicking an output cell.)

Answer (score 1):

4)

```
SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@  Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]
```

But I would choose Szabolcs's 3rd solution.